# Why do my app gets OutOfMemoryError Metaspace using play framework?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Im working with play writing apps in scala for a while now and I got the chance to build several applications with play and scala before, and for all I use the same sbt configuration. And also im working on this specific project for 2 months now and never got out of memory exception, but yesterday at some point I was testing my apis using postman and out of no were i get this error:

[image]

no idea where it came from, I closed the app and run it again and it worked again.

in my `build.sbt` I have java options:

```
javaOptions in Universal ++= Seq(
  // -J params will be added as jvm parameters
  "-J-Xms32m",
  "-J-Xmx32m",
  "-J-server",
)
```

but I have the same thing with other applications and no issue at all...

Im suspecting:
maybe because when working locally im changing code and then a libary im using doing allot of printing at recompiling, so maybe if im working allot when the app runs and doing allot of changes and recompiling while running allot this can cause this issue?

would appreciate some help her please

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Stopping/cleaning-up

Comment: make sure you are using latest play possible.  There are memory leaks in the framework under specific dev conditions that may have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to just increase the sbt `metaspace size` until you can work for a few hours without this exception. Then, restart sbt once in a while.

```
sbt -mem 2048
```